# Partial WordPress Multisite Migration

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have a WordPress Multisite that I use for several projects while they're in development - and then migrate a single install when I'm moving to a new server / domain.

The problem I'm running into, is that I have 3 sites within this multisite install (of 6+ sites total) that I need migrate to a different server, but am not sure how to only export only the parts of the database that are needed for these 3 sites (with wp id's of 6, 7 and 8).

I've been using [this guide](http://wpengine.com/support/how-to-change-a-multi-site-primary-domain/) - which is slightly problematic since I only need THREE of the sites databases exported, but still need (at least some) of the multisite tables exported as well.

Any one know of any links to guide me in the right direction? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest exporting all of the context via something like All-in-on-migration (you'll need the premium version for multisite) (documentation is POOR) and then exporting it all as the most up to date version, then removing what you don't need.

Partial migrations are a pain. I've not managed to do one that's not very messy. It's a problem I am trying to solve right now. Hence coming across this post.